# AWS - Error 504 - Gateway timeout - Flask Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Yesterday I deployed on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk my first flask app.
App is working, but there is a problem when I press a button that launch a scraping process.
This process is pretty long, it can takes about 3/4 minutes, and obviously after one minute from i pressed the button i got the 504 error.

I read a lot on internet on how solve this problem and it is related to nginx, but nothing is working.

This is what I have tried:

**1. EC2 Load Balancer**
I have created a load balancer linked to my istance, and increased the idle timeout to 300s. But nothing changed.

**2. Added .ebextensions to my project**
I also tried to modify nginx parameters with my_name.conf inside

```
.ebextensions -> nginx -> conf.d -> my_name.conf
```

*my_name.conf*

```
keepalive_timeout 240s
proxy_read_timeout 240s;
proxy_send_timeout 240s;
proxy_connect_timeout 240s;
```

and alone in `.ebextensions`

*proxy.config*

```
container_commands:
    01_reload_nginx:
        command: 'sudo service nginx reload'
```

Neither this solution worked.

So I tried another approach

In `.ebextensions` i create this file, but didn't work, then i tried to put in `.ebextensions -> nginx` , but again the problem still remain.

*proxy.config*

```
files:
    “/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-timeout.conf”:
        mode: “000644”
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            keepalive_timeout 240s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 240s;
            proxy_send_timeout 240s;
            proxy_read_timeout 240s;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 240s;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240s;
container_commands:
    nginx_reload:
        command: “sudo service nginx reload”
```

My project structure is:

```
my_app
-> .ebextensions
->project (where there are python file with all the code)
->application.py (python file wiith main used to load all the file and launch the app)
->requirements.txt
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to change the Idle Timeout via settings somehow? Because i dont want to configure it manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nginx` settings you are trying to use (/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-timeout.conf`) are for **Amazon Linux 1**.

Its likely that you are using **Amazon Linux 2**, for which the nginx settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)).

Therefore, you could try the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/mytimeout.conf` with content:

```
keepalive_timeout 240s;
proxy_connect_timeout 240s;
proxy_send_timeout 240s;
proxy_read_timeout 240s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 240s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 240s;
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, man, you made my day.
I am really grateful to you, my bad, but i didn't search really well and i didn't find that page.
Thanks again @Marcin